# My SQL Server database table on datagridview won't show up in .NET 6.0 but it used to work in .NET 4.8

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

I have a problem of trying get my SQL Server database table working in my datagridview as all the buttons are working except the view all button which worked in my .NET 4.8 form.

I coded like this in my .NET 4.8 form and it worked:

```
private void btnViewAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
     cn.ConnectionString = cs;
     cn.Open();

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.Connection = cn;
     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Recipes";

     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
     da.SelectCommand = cmd;

     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     da.Fill(dt);

     dgvRecipes.DataSource = dt;

     cmd.Dispose();
     da.Dispose();
     cn.Close();
     cn.Dispose();
}
```

If needed I could send my entire code, I just want to understand why is this not working despite all my other button working in .NET 6.0.

Comment: if your button is not working then check `EventHandler` is subscribed to `OnClick` Event.
and if button is Clicked but not getting data then use `try` `catch` block to determine the error

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Introducing the new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/)